# How do I retrieve the UID's that I have placed as documents in my Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am currently using expo react-native to create a feed in which all user posts could be retrieved, I have come up with a solution to input all of the current users posts

```
 const Posts = firebase.firestore().collection("posts").doc(user.uid).collection("userPosts");
   const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

   useEffect(async () =>{
     Posts
     .onSnapshot(
       querySnapshot => { 
         const users = []
         querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
           const { caption, creation, DownloadURL} = doc.data()
           users.push({
             id: doc.id,
             caption,
             creation,
             DownloadURL,
           })
         })
         setUsers(users)
       }
     ) 
   }, [])
```

but I could not find a way to get retrieve all the UID's of all the users with posts in order for me to access all the posts, my database goes as follows:
posts(base collection with UID's of users)->userPosts( with UIDS of each post and fields for posts )

For reference I have also tried using the same format but to no avail as I tried to pass the values and it led to 'undefined', closest I have gone is get this on the console log: [image]

The code for the above is here:

```
const AllUids = firebase.firestore().collection("posts");
  const [uids, setUids] = useState([]);

  useEffect(async () =>{
    AllUids
    .onSnapshot(
      querySnapshot => { 
        const uids = []
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const {id} = doc.data()
          uids.push({
            id: doc.id,
            id
        
          })
        })
        setUids(uids)
      }
    ) 
  }, [])
  console.log(uids)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both loading data from Firestore and setting modifying the state in a React app are asynchronous operations, so by the time your `console.log(uids)` runs neither of those will have completed yet.

The easiest way to log the `uid` value, is to use another effect that depends on that state variable:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(uids);
}, [uids]);
```

This has been coming up repeatedly in the past days, but I'm not sure why folks are suddenly bumping into this more than before.

Comment: Hey frank ! Thanks for the help, I'm not sure why but its still giving me the same undefined error, i still used the same base code for const uids, it just has less array inputs now, Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hello again, im jsut double checking, correct me if im wrong tho, from the initial code all i needed to change was the consolelog into the code that you pasted? Thanks a lot !

Comment: You'll need to use/add another effect, that depends on the `uids` state variable - so that it triggers **after** the state is set.